# Most efficient way to filter pandas rows based on row-wise comparison to columns from another dataframe?

Tags: python-2.7, pandas, numpy

I'm going to have trouble verbalizing this, so I'll just include some code and describe what I need to do afterward instead:

```
import pandas as pd

start = [1, 5, 102, 300]
end = [3, 90, 150, 304]

df1 = pd.DataFrame({'start':start, 'end':end})

df2 = pd.DataFrame([0, 3, 10, 14, 100, 101, 102, 113, 300])
df2.columns=["bp_pos"]
```

So, for every start-end pair, I need to check if any of my values in df2 fall within that range. If they do, I need to exclude that index from df2.

I have this working. The problem is that my I have 22 df1s, and each one is a few million rows, and my df2 is also a few million rows. This gets really slow with my solution, which looks something like:

```
for idx, row in df1.iterrows():
    df2 = df2.loc[~((row['start'] <= df2['bp_pos']) &
                   (row['end'] >= df2['bp_pos']))]
```

I'm hoping to get a faster solution than what I have above. Are there faster solutions you can think of? I'm using Python 2.7.12, and Pandas/NumPy solutions accepted. (Sorry if the code above doesn't actually work- I don't have Python on the PC I'm posting from)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would get an array of your values that you want to exclude, then use normal `pandas` indexing:

```
vals = np.concatenate([np.arange(x,y) for x,y in zip(start,end)])

df2[~df2['bp_pos'].isin(vals)]

   bp_pos
0       0
1       3
4     100
5     101
```

Just as further explanation: `vals` ends up being an array of all your ranges:

```
>>> vals
array([  1,   2,   5,   6,   7,   8,   9,  10,  11,  12,  13,  14,  15,
        16,  17,  18,  19,  20,  21,  22,  23,  24,  25,  26,  27,  28,
        29,  30,  31,  32,  33,  34,  35,  36,  37,  38,  39,  40,  41,
        42,  43,  44,  45,  46,  47,  48,  49,  50,  51,  52,  53,  54,
        55,  56,  57,  58,  59,  60,  61,  62,  63,  64,  65,  66,  67,
        68,  69,  70,  71,  72,  73,  74,  75,  76,  77,  78,  79,  80,
        81,  82,  83,  84,  85,  86,  87,  88,  89, 102, 103, 104, 105,
       106, 107, 108, 109, 110, 111, 112, 113, 114, 115, 116, 117, 118,
       119, 120, 121, 122, 123, 124, 125, 126, 127, 128, 129, 130, 131,
       132, 133, 134, 135, 136, 137, 138, 139, 140, 141, 142, 143, 144,
       145, 146, 147, 148, 149, 300, 301, 302, 303])
```

Comment: Thanks! I can't upvote because of reputation, but I was hoping for a solution like the zip you just showed.

Comment: You're welcome! If it's what you needed, you can accept my answer by clicking the check mark below the vote counts :)